# How do I send an email using NextJS and Wordpress REST API?

Tags: wordpress, email, next.js

I'm building a new site using NextJS and Wordpress for the backend. I serve data from my Wordpress site with no problem at all but...how do I send an email using a contact form with the Wordpress REST API. You can achieve this using Wordpress plugins, but, how do you do that without them? I'm not an expert on PHP, so any help/indication is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You can try using something like nodemailer to send emails directly from your next js app.

Comment: Yes! That’s one option, would that work if I create a new API route endpoint in NextJS 9 or should I create a custom server.js for that functionality?

Comment: If you don't have any use for a custom server for other tasks go ahead with API endpoints.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that way!